# Query to Get Maximum Length of Field from DataTable

Tags: vb.net, postgresql, linq, datatable

I'm working on a function that will use a `DataTable` to create a new table in a PostgreSQL database.  I'm trying to "improve" on the code found in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/riyadparvez/4467819) and convert it to VB.NET for my environment, but I'm having some difficulty when trying to get some of the PostgreSQL column definitions out of the `DataTable` definitions.

In my code, I'm taking the original `DataTable` (***`SourceData`***), converting it to a `DataReader` and then calling the [`GetSchemaTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatablereader.getschematable?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Data_DataTableReader_GetSchemaTable) method to get the field definitions

```
Dim TempReader As DataTableReader = SourceData.CreateDataReader
Dim SchemaTable As DataTable = TempReader.GetSchemaTable()
```

This works fine in general but one limitation of this method is, if the fields of the DataTable haven't been explicitly constructed with certain properties (e.g., `NumericPrecision` or `NumericScale` for `Decimal` types), the schema table isn't able to properly provide this information to my table creation code.  The Gist apparently handles this by simply defining any `Decimal` columns without these values explicitly specified to `Integer` columns.  That doesn't work for me.

What I'd like to do is query that column in the original `DataTable` for the maximum length of the field - more specifically, the number of digits after the decimal point in any field of `Decimal` type (I'd also like to do something similar for `DateTime` fields in the `DataTable` to determine whether or not I need to include the time when I create the field in PostgreSQL).

Here is an example of the code I'm using to get the PostgreSQL column definitions.  It's ***absolutely incomplete*** right now (I need to add handling for default values, not NULL, etc.), and I'm probably going to need to change the method definition to pass most of the variables I've defined as parameters in order to truly accomplish what I'm asking for, but this is what I'm starting with.

```
Private Function GetColumnTypeDefinition(ByVal TableSchemaRow As DataRow) As String
    Dim ColumnTypeDefinition As String = "character varying"

    Dim CurrentType As String = Convert.ToString(TableSchemaRow("DataType"))
    Dim ColumnSize As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(TableSchemaRow("ColumnSize"))
    Dim AutoIncrement As Boolean = Convert.ToBoolean(TableSchemaRow("IsAutoIncrement"))
    Dim AllowNull As Boolean = Convert.ToBoolean(TableSchemaRow("AllowDBNull"))
    Dim NumericScale As Integer = 0
    Dim NumericPrecision As Integer = 0
    Dim DefaultValue As String = String.Empty

    If Not IsCellEmpty(TableSchemaRow("DefaultValue")) Then
        DefaultValue = Convert.ToString(TableSchemaRow("DefaultValue"))
    End If

    ' TOTAL NUMBER OF DIGITS IN A NUMBER (BEFORE AND AFTER A DECIMAL POINT)
    If Not IsCellEmpty(TableSchemaRow("NumericPrecision")) Then
        NumericPrecision = Convert.ToInt32(TableSchemaRow("NumericPrecision"))
    End If

    ' NUMBER OF DIGITS AFTER THE DECIMAL POINT IN A NUMBER
    If Not IsCellEmpty(TableSchemaRow("NumericScale")) Then
        NumericScale = Convert.ToInt32(TableSchemaRow("NumericScale"))
    End If

    Select Case CurrentType.ToString
        Case "System.Boolean"
            ColumnTypeDefinition = "boolean"
        Case "System.String"
            If ColumnSize = -1 Then
                ColumnTypeDefinition = "character varying"
            Else
                ColumnTypeDefinition = "character varying(" & ColumnSize & ")"
            End If
        Case "System.Decimal"
            If NumericScale > 0 Then
                If NumericPrecision > 0 Then
                    ColumnTypeDefinition = "numeric(" & NumericPrecision & "," & NumericScale & ")"
                Else
                    ColumnTypeDefinition = "numeric(" & NumericScale + 1 & "," & NumericScale & ")"
                End If
            ElseIf NumericPrecision > 10 Then
                ColumnTypeDefinition = "bigint"
            Else
                ' >> THIS IS WHERE I WOULD WANT TO QUERY THE ORIGINAL 
                ' DATATABLE INSTEAD OF JUST AUTOMATICALLY DEFAULTING 
                ' TO AN INTEGER DATATYPE <<
                ColumnTypeDefinition = "integer"
            End If
        Case "System.Double"
            ColumnTypeDefinition = "double precision"
        Case "System.Single"
            ColumnTypeDefinition = "real"
        Case "System.Int64", "System.Long"
            If AutoIncrement Then
                ColumnTypeDefinition = "bigserial"
            Else
                ColumnTypeDefinition = "bigint"
            End If
        Case "System.Int32", "System.Integer"
            If AutoIncrement Then
                ColumnTypeDefinition = "serial"
            Else
                ColumnTypeDefinition = "integer"
            End If
        Case "System.Int16", "System.Short"
            If AutoIncrement Then
                ColumnTypeDefinition = "smallserial"
            Else
                ColumnTypeDefinition = "smallint"
            End If
        Case "System.DateTime"

        Case Else
            Throw New NotImplementedException(CurrentType.ToString & " not implemented.")
    End Select

    Return ColumnTypeDefinition
End Function
```

While I'm pretty familiar with SQL, I'm much less familiar with Linq.  In PostgreSQL, I'd probably just write a query that says something like (I tested this query and it *appears* to work correctly):

```
SELECT MAX(length(split_part(<decimalfieldname>::text, '.', 2))) FROM <tablename>
```

Is there a decent way to accomplish this same goal with a Linq query (or anything else) against the original `DataTable`?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: So after reading all of that, you have two questions: 1) How to determine the scale of a Decimal type? and 2) how to determine if a DateTime has a time component?  -- Is that correct?

Comment: That *is* the end goal, but if I can *at least* get the max length, I might be able to work through some of the other details.  If there's a way to get that type of information directly from `DataTable` columns that don't have that information explicitly defined, that would be awesome!

Comment: As far as I know, that type of schema information is not stored in a DataTable when filled from an adapter.   The only way I know of would be to scan the data rows and extract said information.  Is the table filled from an existing DB? If so, why not use the schema from that DB. If it is not and you want to pursue, the brute-force scan, then I can post code that determines the scale of a Decimal.  I can't believe that you would need to be shown how to determine if a DateTime has a time component other than the default.

Comment: The DataTable in question is being filled from a plain text file, hence the lack of specific definition for Decimal fields. I was hoping for a Linq query of some sort to approximate the SQL query above, but if brute force is the only way to get it, then I can loop through the data pretty easily. Although, if you've got something that was specifically written to determine the precision of a Decimal field, I'd gladly take a look. As for the DateTime field, I don't *need* to know, but I'd *like* to know to make the function as "thorough" as possible.

Comment: Any explanation for the downvote would be appreciated. I attempted to give enough detail to anyone that might be able to provide an answer so as to minimize confusion, but I would certainly be open to how the question can be improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handling the `DateTime` part is easy enough:

```
Dim HasTime = dataTable.Any(Function (d) d.dateTimeColumn.TimeOfDay <> TimeSpan.Zero)
```

I think the best you can do is something similar to your SQL query that converts to string and gets the length after the decimal point:

```
Dim DecimalScale = Users.Where(Function (d) d.Userid.ToString().IndexOf(".") >= 0).Select(Function (d) d.Userid.ToString().Length-d.Userid.ToString().IndexOf(".")-1).Max()
```

Comment: Required a bit of finalization (looks like it came out of C#, and I needed it to be a bit flexible when it comes to the field names), but I got it to work, and it appears to be working *EXACTLY* as I want.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I primarily use C# and tried to convert to VB on the fly :) - and I see I didn't do a good job.

Comment: Well, it gave me a good jumping off point so I could get to my goal.  I had to add some additional testing/validation to the `.Where` clause for NULL values, and the `.DefaultIfEmpty` clause to the `DecimalScale` expression to prevent some runtime exceptions, but it seems to be handling it all like a champ now.

Comment: Well, I fixed the VB syntax anyway, glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

The decimal structure is well defined in the [documentation of it constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1de0ya1.aspx) that takes an array of integers.

You can retrieve this defining array of an existing `Decimal` using the [Decimal.GetBits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.getbits(v=vs.110).aspx).  Once you have this array, it is just a matter of bit manipulation to retrieve scale factor of a Decimal that defines the number of digits to the right of the decimal mark in a `Decimal`'s string representation.

The following is written as an extension method for the `Decimal` type.

```
Module DecimalExtensions

    <Extension()>
    Public Function Scale(d As Decimal) As Int32
        ' From: Decimal Constructor (Int32[]) - Remarks
        ' https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1de0ya1(v=vs.100).aspx

        ' The binary representation of a Decimal number consists of a 1-bit sign, 
        ' a 96-bit integer number, and a scaling factor used to divide 
        ' the integer number and specify what portion of it is a decimal fraction. 
        ' The scaling factor is implicitly the number 10, raised to an exponent ranging from 0 to 28.

        ' bits is a four-element long array of 32-bit signed integers.
        Dim bits As Int32() = Decimal.GetBits(d)

        ' bits [0], bits [1], and bits [2] contain the low, middle, and high 32 bits of the 96-bit integer number.

        ' bits [3] contains the scale factor and sign, and consists of following parts:
        ' Bits 0 to 15, the lower word, are unused and must be zero.
        ' Bits 16 to 23 must contain an exponent between 0 and 28, 
        ' which indicates the power of 10 to divide the integer number.

        ' i.e.: the number digits to the right of the decimal mark
        ' so, mask off bits 0 to 15 --> lower 2 bytes, and the upper byte
        ' mask = &H00FF0000
        Dim mask As Int32 = &HFF0000
        Dim masked As Int32 = bits(3) And mask

        ' shift masked value 16 bits to the left to obtain the scaleFactor
        Dim scaleFactor As Int32 = masked >> 16
        Return scaleFactor
    End Function
End Module
```

Example usage:

```
Dim d1 As Decimal = 1.0123456789012345678901234567D
Debug.Print(d1.Scale.ToString()) ' prints 28
d1 = 1D
Debug.Print(d1.Scale.ToString()) ' prints 0

d1 = 1.1D
Debug.Print(d1.Scale.ToString()) ' prints 1

d1 = 12345678901234567890.012345679D
Debug.Print(d1.Scale.ToString()) ' prints 10
```

You mention in the comments that the DataTable is filled from a CSV.  Hopefully, you are parsing to strong types before adding the values to the DataTable.  That would be an opportune time to determine these precision metrics as it would eliminate the need to post-process each row and its associated cost.

Comment: One correction about my comment: It isn't actually a CSV (*comma*-separated values) file, it's a plain text, fixed-length file that I'm loading through an OleDb connection using a SCHEMA.INI.

Regardless, I really like this method of determining the precision of individual Decimal values.  This would be great for if I am looping through all of the rows in the DataTable (or another list of Decimal values)

The Linq query posted by @NetMage (after a bit of "tweaking") seems to accomplish my goal for an entire column at a time, but I have a feeling I'll be incorporating *this* code as well.

Comment: You really need to get over the LINQ fixation.  If you think that there is no enumeration of the datarows happening with that you are very much mistaken.

Comment: I don't think anything of the kind.  I could write a `For...Next` or `For Each` loop and enumerate it myself, or I could let Linq do all the "heavy lifting" for me.  It's not a "fixation" with Linq, it's just trying to find the most appropriate tool for the job.  There are plenty of cases where I need to loop through a set of DataRows, and I do it frequently for one reason or another.  As I said, I have no doubt that your code will come in handy in a number of scenarios, so I truly appreciate your contribution.